# How does Padrino map :index to '/'?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, url-routing, padrino

I'm curious how Padrino accomplishes mapping:

```
get :index do
```

to:

```
get '/' do
```

I'm having trouble finding it in the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply overrides the `get` method, i.e.:

```
alias old_get get

def get(path)
  if path == :index
    old_get '/'
  else
    old_get path
  end
end
```